# In vim, how can I move text to certain columns?

Tags: vim

I have text files of poems with line numbers on the right that look like this:

```
Bedded in store of rotten fig-leaves soft,   40
And corded up in a tight olive-frail,   
Some lump, ah God, of lapis lazuli, 
Big as a Jew’s head cut off at the nape,    
Blue as a vein o’er the Madonna’s breast    
Sons, all have I bequeathed you, villas, all,        45
```

Where the spaces between the ends of the lines and the line numbers are not consistent. How can I move the numbers to a particular column, so that they line up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A powerful method to solve problems with vim is to use macros and elementary commands, because those are simpler to remember then the vim scripting language.

In this case, I would place the cursor before number, which is the last word in the row (to do this: `$b`); insert a lot of spaces; remove the extraneous ones (if you want to use row 61, do: `061ldw`); go to next line (to do this: `j`).

You first press `qa` to start recording macro "a", then press these keys above (and no others) and press `q` to finish recording. Now to use it, use `@a` for macro "a"; after that, keep pressing `@@` (repeat last macro) until you get to the end of the text.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that `dw` would delete whitespace, or that `061l` would get me to column 61, although that seems completely obvious now.

Comment: You can use the `|` to jump to a column number without first needing to jump to the first column like `061l` does. instead `61|` anywhere will jump to that column (assuming you have characters that reach that column otherwise you will jump to the end of the line)

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to achieve basically the same but for certain characters in software code. The characters can appear anywhere on the line but I wanted them (and anything to the right of them) to appear on a specific column. For example:

```
refclkp : in std_logic;
refclkn : in std_logic;
hdinp_ch0 : in std_logic;
hdinn_ch0 : in std_logic;
hdoutp_ch0 : out std_logic;
```

I wanted it to look like this:

```
refclkp                    : in std_logic;
refclkn                    : in std_logic;
hdinp_ch0                  : in std_logic;
hdinn_ch0                  : in std_logic;
hdoutp_ch0                 : out std_logic;
```

I.e. with all the `:` on a specific column (column 30 in this case). The above didn't make sense to me (it may work but I don't use the visual stuff) but it did give me the clue to solving it:

```
:map H $?:<ctrl+Enter>Di                              <ctrl+Esc>029lP:s/\s*$//<ctrl+Enter>
```

You do the `<ctrl+Enter>` and `<ctrl+Esc>` bits by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It appears in the command as `^M` or `^[`. The above essentially does this:

1. Go to the end of the line (`$`)
2. look backwards for the first ":" (`?:<ctrl+Enter>`)
3. Delete everything from this point to the end of the line (`D`)
4. Insert 30 spaces - this is so I know there is enough white space to allow me to jump to column 30 (`i                              <ctrl+Esc>`)
5. Jump to Column 30 - not sure why I need to use '29' here, must be a 'feature' (`029l`)
6. Paste the deleted text from step 3 (`P`)
7. Clean up by deleting all the trailing white spaces created in step 4 (`:s/\s*$//<ctrl+Enter>`)

I created this as a mapping so all I need to do now is hit <kbd>H</kbd> and the current line is modified!

Comment: In `029l`, the `0` takes you to column 1. The `29l` says move 29 columns to the right of 1. 29  + 1 = 30. It's a good trick, but there's an even better option in Vim, [the `|` command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9953097/27581), so you can just do `30|` to go to column 30.

Comment: I use [this method](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20670/27564). While it looks complicated at first, it's quite easy and fast to use after a few times. After step 8 you can use a `.` to repeat the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The another method for this kind of column alignment is like this :

let us take the above example,

before :

```
refclkp : in std_logic;
refclkn : in std_logic;
hdinp_ch0 : in std_logic;
hdinn_ch0 : in std_logic;
hdoutp_ch0 : out std_logic;
```

after :

```
refclkp       : in std_logic;
refclkn       : in std_logic;
hdinp_ch0     : in std_logic;
hdinn_ch0     : in std_logic;
hdoutp_ch0    : out std_logic;
```

Here I aligned the "**:**" character at the 15th column.
for doing this follow the below steps:

1. Go to the first line (where we need to start the changes, here it is "**refclkp : in std_logic;**")
2. Then Press the `<Esc>` key to go to the normal mode
3. Pres these keys

   `qa0f:i         (Press the space bar more than 20 times)<Esc>15|dw<DownArrow>q`
4. Then press `4@a` for repeating the same for remaining 4 lines.

(Here the spaces more than 20 is for our safe side can change with respect your requirement)

Comment: Hi David, I know this is not answering the actual question.
I was describing an alternate solution for the 2nd answer